# Visual Studio C++ error reading location

Tags: c++, algorithm, visual-studio

I'm having I guess a simple problem. I'm practicing in coding binary tree(first time, maybe in a year, that I've looked again at C++). So, when I launch my code in VS 2013, I get an error "unhandled exception .... reading location `address`". And when I try debugging it, after creating root tree and trying to add first leaf, happens, that right and left leaves already have some addresses, but don't have any values(they are pointed as Unable to read memory).

But, when I load this code into some online compiler, it works perfectly. So maybe it's some settings in VS, because I don't have any other variants, why it works in online compiler and doesn't work in VS.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Node 
{
    string value;
    int key;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
};

void addNodeToTree(Node* tree, int key, string value)
{
    if (key < tree->key) 
    {
        if (tree->left != nullptr)
        {
            addNodeToTree(tree->left, key, value);
        }
        else
        {
            Node* node = new Node();
            node->key = key;
            node->value = value;
            cout << "Key " << key << " leaf has been successfully added to the left" << endl;
            tree->left = node;

        }
    }
    else if (key > tree->key)
    {
        if (tree->right != nullptr)
        {
            addNodeToTree(tree->right, key, value);
        }
        else
        {
            Node* node = new Node();
            node->key = key;
            node->value = value;
            cout << "Key " << key << " leaf has been successfully added to the right" << endl;
            tree->right = node;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Key " << key << " already exists." << endl;
    }
}

void PrintTree(Node* node)
{
    if (node != NULL)
    {
        if (node->left != NULL) 
        {
            PrintTree(node->left);
        }
        cout << node->key << " ";
        if (node->right != NULL)
        {
            PrintTree(node->right);
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        cout << "The tree is empty";
    }
}

int main() {
    Node* tree = new Node();
    tree->key = 50;
    tree->value = 2591;

    addNodeToTree(tree, 20, "124525");
    addNodeToTree(tree, 80, "124525");
    addNodeToTree(tree, 10, "124525");
    addNodeToTree(tree, 30, "124525");
    addNodeToTree(tree, 50, "124525");

    PrintTree(tree);

    delete tree;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: On what line of code is your error?

Comment: It's most likely a bug and not a VS setting issue. Are you asking us to go over your code and find the bug?

Comment: Is `tree->value = 2591;` a typo? Did you mean to use `tree->value = "2591";`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a VS error - when you allocate the `Node` structure the `left` and `right` member fields are uninitialized, so your checks against `nullptr` further on fail even though the `left`/`right` nodes are empty and you operate on invalid nodes.

Solution 1:

Use a class instead of a struct and initialize the fields in the constructor:

```
class Node 
{
public:
    Node() : left(nullptr), right(nullptr), key(0)
    {
    }

    string value;
    int key;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
};
```

Solution 2:

Use a function that creates and initializes a new node:

```
struct Node 
{
    string value;
    int key;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
};

Node* createNode(int key = 0)
{
    Node* node = new Node();
    node->left = nullptr;
    node->right = nullptr;
    node->key = key;
    return node;
}
```

Or as suggested in the comments add a constructor to the struct:

```
struct Node 
{
    Node() : left(nullptr), right(nullptr), key(0)
    {
    }

    string value;
    int key;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
};
```

Solution 3:

If C++11 is available, use data member initializers (but this is not supported in VS as far as I know):

```
struct Node 
{
    string value;
    int key = 0;
    Node* left = nullptr;
    Node* right = nullptr;
};
```

Comment: It's not a crime to use constructors with structs - there's no need to make it a class.

Comment: @molbdnilo will edit, thanks for the tip, I wasn't objective as my personal preference is to avoid structs if they are not POD containers, so forgot about this:)

Comment: Why would you *prefer* to create a function which **constructs** a node rather than use a constructor? That makes zero sense.

Comment: @Barry - quite hard acquisitions my friend, if an empty constructor is used the struct is no longer a POD, meaning aggregate initialization cannot be used  any more. I clearly stated that at least my personal preference is to use structs for POD data types, and in that context it makes sense:)

Answer (score 4):

You need to initialize and free your `Node`s correctly. You are accessing `left` and `right` without having initialized them, which is undefined behavior:

```
struct Node
{
    Node(int key, const string& value)
        : value(value)
        , key(key)
        , left(0)
        , right(0)
    { }

    ~Node() {
        delete left;
        delete right;
    }        

    string value;
    int key;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
};
```

And propagate that throughout your code. Additionally,

```
tree->value = 2591;
```

should be:

```
tree->value = "2591";
```